# valueChangeListner is not working for JSF checkbox

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am facing problem in calling valueChangeListner method for h:selectManyCheckbox

this is my code

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox id="subscriptions" value="#{searchResults.customerSegmantSearchDetails}" layout="pageDirection" valueChangeListner="#{fxViewHelper.getCustomerSegmentList}">
<a4j:ajax event="valueChange" execute="@this" limitRender="true"/><f:selectItem id="item1" itemLabel="" itemValue="#{searchResults}"/> </h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

here h:selectManyCheckbox value contains List and f:selectItem value contains Object

in ManageBean i am just printing value

```
public void getCustomerSegmentList(ValueChangeEvent event) {

    System.out.println(event.getNewValue());

}
```

but nothing is printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you misspelled the attribute.
Change `valueChangeListner="..."` to `valueChangeListener="..."` and it should work. There is an 'e' missing.